# Get custom html attribute from <select> control with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I was wondering what am I doing wrong here?

I have the following HTML:

```
<select name="somename" id="DropDownList1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1" valp="7700000000000000">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2" valp="7C08000000000000">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3" valp="5800000000000000">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

And the following JS/JQuery code that is called when the page loads:

```
$('#DropDownList1').change(function () {
    onChangeDropDownList1(this);
});

function onChangeDropDownList1(obj) {
    var vP = $(obj).attr('valp');
    alert("valp=" + vP);
};
```

As the result I get "valp=undefined"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` in context of the `.change()` refers to the `<select>` rather than the `<option>`, so you're not getting the node with the `valp` attribute.

```
$('#DropDownList1').change(function () {
    onChangeDropDownList1(this);
});

function onChangeDropDownList1(obj) {
    // Get the selected option
    var vP = $(obj).find(':selected').attr('valp');
    alert("valp=" + vP);
};
```

[Here is a demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/uJBjb/)

Answer (score 2):

The `change` function is providing you the `select` which was updated not the `option`.  You need to query the `:selected` value out of it.  Once you have the selected option you can query for the `valp` attribute

```
function onChangeDropDownList1(obj) {
    var vP = $(obj).find('option:selected').attr('valp');
    alert("valp=" + vP);
};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jpfs3/

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `option`, not the `select`:

```
onChangeDropDownList1($(this).children(':selected'));
```

or, grab the option from the passed `select`:

```
var vP = $($(obj).children(':selected')).attr('valp');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the JS code before the end of the body